# Declaring marital status in the US passport application form DS 11

Tags: united-states, marriage, passport, naturalization

I was just approved for the oath ceremony for US citizenship. While trying to complete the DS 11 form, I noticed that they ask about the marital status, date, etc. I don't have an issue with declaring the info, but my concern is that I got married after I filed the N400 form but before the naturalization interview. I did not report the status change because I was worried about possible delays, because the application was already taking a long time as it was.

Is there an issue when they see it in the DS form now?

Comment: Were you supposed to have reported the change?

Comment: Did you discuss your marital status with the interviewer?

Comment: Have you taken the oath yet?

Comment: If you were required to report the change and didn’t, you could be in serious trouble.